# Enums scope declaration error

Tags: .net, enums, scope

I have namespace with enums:

```
namespace Search
{
    enum SearchConditionType
    {
        Like = 0,
        EqualNotString = 1,
        EqualString = 2
    };
}
```

Then I try to declare enum:

```
namespace Search
{

    public partial class Controls_SelectYesNo : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        public SearchConditionType Field;
        ...
```

And got an error:

> The type or namespace name '' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in next: I made a web application from web site. In web site enums was situated in App_Code folder. When I rename this folder - problem disappears.

Answer (score 3):

```
 enum SearchConditionType
```

Your enum is not public.

Comment: assuming Controls_SelectYesNo and SearchConditionType are in different assemblies, that's probably the correct answer

Comment: How to place them in a same assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Make the enum `public`:

```
public enum SearchConditionType
{
    Like = 0,
    EqualNotString = 1,
    EqualString = 2
};
```

Types that do not have an access modifier default to `internal` in C#.

If the files are in different assemblies, you need to add a reference to the assembly containingn the enum. This can be done through the `References` node of the project in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @Randolpho - I am not trying to guess whether this should be internal or public. Perhpas it should be public - depends on what it is used for, whether it is indeed an internal implementation detail or not.

Comment: @Oded: I meant the default access modifier for a type is "internal", not "private"

Comment: @Anton - are the files in the same assembly/project?

Comment: It is separate web application. How to place them in a same assembly?

Comment: @Anton - then you need to add a reference to it. See my updated answer.

Comment: All files now situated in one project, but I am still getting error.

Comment: @Anton - Are you sure they all have the same namespace? Are you sure it is the line declaring the enum field that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, I am sure all have the same namespace. And that line cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... you *are* attempting to expose an internal type as a public type. That's the only problem I see with your code. But it shouldn't cause the compiler error you're providing, so I'm thinking maybe the problem is elsewhere in your code.

*edit*: Are you trying to expose the enum in another assembly? That'd cause the error you're listing. So, yeah, just make the enum public.

Comment: How to place them in a same assembly?

Comment: @Anton: if you've made the enum public... this should work. Did you add a reference to the assembly containing the now public enum?